# In Clash Of Clans can you deploy troops outside the border like you can in personal attacking

Tags: clash-of-clans

One of my clan mates built his base with the town hall in the corner of his base for war and claims they cannot deploy troops outside the border like normal attacking.

Comment: I'd be glad to war against your friends' clan!

Comment: This is usually the first mistake any one does in CoC, thinking that they cannot attack from land/sea and keeping TH in corner.

Comment: Your friend's strategy will pretty much guarantee that anybody that attacks him or her will score 1 star.

Answer (score 5):

Whether you are trophy farming or not, you can always place troops 2 spaces or further away from any building. This is true since the 2016 update. Prior to that there was always 1 space (tile) in which to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen those kind of bases.

Its really nice to take those things out because its **really easy** to get at least 1 star.

Yes he can get attacked from outside the border.